# How to extract a method which is using "using" keyword and is disposable

Tags: c#, oop, dispose

I have around 20 methods, most of them requires `UserPrincipalExtension` disposable class to do some different operations, I want to extract it into a separate method, but I am not sure how to,

```
public static UserPrincipalExtension GetUPE(Identity type, string identity)
    {
        using (PrincipalContext pc = MyUtilities.GetPrincipalContext())
        using (UserPrincipalExtension UPE = UserPrincipalExtension.FindByIdentity(pc, type, identity))
        {
             // do different operations
            // if I return UPE here then would pc going to dispose itself ?
        }

     // how best to return UPE and dipose pc as well, return UPE;
    }
```

So I can use it in other methods like this:

```
var UPE = GetUPE(IdentityType.SID, "S-32sldkfjsldr344");
using(UPE)
{

}
```

`UPE` and `PrincipalContext` should be disposed afterwords.

Comment: There's no way to do that if you can't make the `UserPrincipalExtension` dispose the `PrincipalContext` as well. Perhaps you could make a wrapper class that handles this for you? Or, if you're not averse to a bit of function-passing, you could make a helper method that manages the `using` and executes your code inside of that. What you have now will simply dispose of the principal context as soon as you `return` - not what you want.

Comment: @Luaan can you find me an example of what you are stating please, I find it hard to understandi it by words, thanks :-)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Unless the UPE has its own way of disposing the principal context, you basically have two options - make a wrapper class around the UPE, or use a helper function.

There's little to be said about the wrapper class approach - simply have a class that has a field for both the PC and the UPE, and have its `Dispose` method dispose of both. Depending on your requirements, either make the UPE public, or expose the methods you need. The simplest possible example would be something like this:

```
class UpeWrapper : IDisposable
{
  public readonly PrincipalContext PrincipalContext;
  public readonly UserPrincipalExtension UserPrincipalExtension;

  public UpeWrapper(PrincipalContext principalContext, 
                    UserPrincipalExtension userPrincipalExtension)
  {
    this.PrincipalContext = principalContext;
    this.UserPrincipalExtension = userPrincipalExtension;
  }

  public void Dispose()
  {
    try
    {
      UserPrincipalExtension.Dispose();
    }
    finally
    {
      PrincipalContext.Dispose();
    }
  }
}
```

Using a helper function is a bit less boilerplate:

```
void UseUserPrincipalExtension(Identity type, string identity, 
                               Action<UserPrincipalExtension> action)
{
  using (PrincipalContext pc = MyUtilities.GetPrincipalContext())
  using (UserPrincipalExtension UPE = 
         UserPrincipalExtension.FindByIdentity(pc, type, identity))
  {
    action(UPE);
  }
}
```

And the usage is quite simple as well:

```
UseUserPrincipalExtension
  (
    a, b, 
    upe => 
    {
      // Do your work here
    }
  );
```

Answer (score 0):

I think one possible way is this, but I am not entirely sure if it going to dispose principalContext for sure and STILL let me use UserPrincipalExtension class which inherits from `System.DirectoryServices.AccountManagement.UserPrincipal`

```
public static UserPrincipalExtension GetUPE(Identity type, string identity)
{
     UserPrincipalExtension UPE = null;
     using (PrincipalContext pc = MyUtilities.GetPrincipalContext())
     {
        UPE = UserPrincipalExtension.FindByIdentity(pc, type, identity));
     }
     return UPE;
}
```

In above method, pc will be disposed, then in other methods,

```
var UPE = GetUPE(IdentityType.SID, "S-32sldkfjsldr344");
using(UPE)
{

}
```

Comment: The principal context will be disposed before the UPE, though - this is likely going to cause some issues.

Comment: @Luaan you are right, it didn't worked, going to try it your way now